# Confusion about step in a proof that no group of order $120$ is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Assume $G$ is simple. Then $n_5 = 6$. Now, we claim that $n_2 = 15$. Indeed, if $n_2 = 3 $ or $n_2 = 5$, *then $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_5$*.

Why is this true? I understand that IF $H \leq G$, then $G \cong \dfrac{G}{H_G}$, which is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ where $n = |G: H |$. And since we're assuming $G$ is simple, $H_G = \{1\}$. But if $H \leq G$ is a $2$ Sylow here, then $|H| = 8$, so we'd have $G \cong S_{15}$, not $S_5$. So what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n_2=5$ let $P_1,.., P_5$ be the 5 2-Sylow groups.

Recall that $G$ acts on the 2-Sylov subgroups via conjugation: $P \to xPx^{-1}$.

Now, each $x \in G$ defines a permutation of $P_1,P_2,.., P_5$.

Show that this is an embedding of $G$ into $S_5$.

Comment: That solves it. Thanks.